# Check if href is a path after the website path

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to check if the href of a link is a file after the website path.  Here is the code:

```js
const currentLocation = location.href;
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('nav ul li a');

$('nav ul li a').each(index => {
    if(menuItems[index].href === currentLocation || (menuItems[index].href === 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/' && currentLocation === 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html')) {
        // other code
    }
});
```

Is there a way to have it to check if it is '/' or '/index.html' after the 'http://127.0.0.1:5500'?  Thank you!

Comment: You can use `endsWith` to make he checks.

Comment: Thank you!  This works.  Here is the updated code:

$('nav ul li a').each(index => {
    if(menuItems[index].href === currentLocation || (menuItems[index].href.endsWith('/') && currentLocation.endsWith('/index.html'))) {
        //other code
    }
});

Comment: Maybe you can put this as an answer, and then I can accept it.  Also, how do you put multiline code in comments?

Comment: Glad I could help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use endsWith to make the checks.

Also instead of this `menuItems[index].href` you can directly check `(menuItems[index].pathname` if you want.